# Does Polymer have a 'componentAppeared' event for components?

Tags: events, polymer, components, polymer-1.0

I want to set focus on a label when component is shown and am wondering if Polymer has something built in for it, if not I'm wondering how others do it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the component code or out of it?

Comment: inside of it... I'm working with neon-animated-pages too... it's within  a neon-animatable

Comment: So, you want to set the focus to a label inside your component once the whole component has been loaded and attached to the main document?

Comment: yes, that is what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`attached` callback](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#initialization-order) which is called once your component is loaded and attached to the dom.

Here's some example code of what you need to do ([and here a jsbin with it working](http://jsbin.com/fefucazoto/edit?html,js,output)):

```
<dom-module id="x-test">
  <template>
    <a id="tofocus" href="/">I'm going to get focused</a>
    <a>but I'm not</a>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-test',
      attached: function () {
        this.$.tofocus.focus();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: This is basically the method I was looking for... however, it does't solve my issue. I'm using neon-animated-pages component and within it I wanted to focus on certain labels as the different pages are shown... with this attached event, all the attached events get triggered on load. Any ideas on fixing this?

Comment: Then you most likely need to listen to the `neon-animation-finish` event

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of `componentAppeared` in Polymer. Every element that is stamped in your DOM is "appeared" so to speak.

It seems you want to display "pages" through the `<neon-animated-pages>` component. Every page that is wrapped inside `<neon-animated-pages>` has already been stamped into DOM - visibility of each page is handled through CSS `display:block`/`display:none` by the controller element

If you want to do stuff *when a page is shown*, you'll have to **wire it up manually**.

```
<neon-animated-pages selected="{{selected}}" on-neon-animation-finish="_focus">

  <neon-animatable class="red" entry-animation="fade-in-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <a id="label0" href="#">Focus me</a>
  </neon-animatable>

  <neon-animatable class="green" entry-animation="fade-in-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <a id="label1" href="#">Focus me</a>
  </neon-animatable>

</neon-animated-pages>
```

...

```
  _focus: function () {
    this.$['label'+this.selected].focus();
  }
```

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/celesobiba/edit?html,console,output